# Can you destroy the Sun if you throw enough iron into it?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astrophysics, sun, estimation, supernova

i have a vague understanding of how the inside of the sun works, but i remember from class that when the sun started "making" iron on it's core, it cannot go further; can't make a heavier element. then it explodes. so, if you were to launch a couple of earth masses of iron into the sun, will it explode? and if so, how much do you need?

Comment: you would need a lot more than a couple of earth masses...

Comment: The Sun will never make iron in its core.